# WebView In Kitkat (4.4) Opens In a New Broswer Window

Tags: java, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

Before I upgraded my android tablet from 4.3 to 4.4, I successfully loaded a webview to prompt a user to login with Google (Using OAuth 2.0) and whenever they clicked Login button, they were redirected to the **Allow Access** window from where they could click allow or deny. All these happened without opening a new browser window.

After upgrading, when I load the webview, this is what I see (which is still okay).

[image]

After a user enters their credentials, instead of being redirected to the consent screen, they see this new web browser (Chrome) window:

[image]

As you can see, this is a regular browser window as opposed to the first one!

The interesting thing here is the fact that it works fine in 4.3 but in 4.4 it does not! Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** Some Code

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
         {
      if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("tumblr.com"))
              {
         return false;
      }

      if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("facebook.com"))
              {
        return false;
      }
          if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("fake.com"))
            {
             return false;
            }
          if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("google.com"))
           {
            return false;
            }

      if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().startsWith("file"))
            {
        return false;
    }

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
      view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
      return true;
    }



       @Override
       public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap bitmap)
       {
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, null);

      if(url.startsWith("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin"))
           {
     view.setInitialScale(100);
       }
       }
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code, particularly your `WebViewClient` implementation.

Comment: I have added some code!

Comment: I have no idea why that would work on any version of Android. You are always loading a Web page in a browser, either by returning `false` or by manually doing it yourself.

Comment: I return false so that it does not open in a new browser.

Comment: `true` means not to open a new browser, and that you're handling the event yourself. `false` means that you want the default `WebView` behavior, which will be to open a new browser.